# First time using MySQLdb in Arch Linux (Manjaro) show error

Tags: python, mysql, linux, archlinux

it's first time i using MySQLdb on python and i using Manjaro, when i tried to run my program. The error always show like :

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, 'Can\'t connect to local MySQL server through socket \'/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock\' (13 "Permission denied")')
```

Many people suggest me to add file mysqld.sock ang yes i did it, but still error with the same error.

And i get suggest to install mysql-client, python-mysql-connector, mysql-python, But still error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this prompt

`"Permission denied"`

I guess your operation may need root privilege.

Comment: I try run as root. and the error is :

_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, 'Can\'t connect to local MySQL server through socket \'/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock\' (111 "Connection refused")')

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Can%27t+connect+to+local+MySQL+server+through+socket+%27%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fmysqld%2Fmysqld.sock%27

Answer (score 0):

From the error mentioned, it looks like the mysql service is not running on your machine.

You have to **start the mysql service** before a connection is made to mysql.

Now, since you have mentioned that you have a **fresh installation**, before you start the mysql service, you have to initialize your MySQL data directory. You can do so with

> mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql

and make sure to secure your installation with

> mysql_secure_installation

and then you can continue with starting the mysql service.

Since you are on Manjaro, you can start mysql service with

> sudo systemctl start mariadb